# Calculating array size inside function?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
void ArraySize(int arrMyarr[])
{
    std::cout << sizeof(arrMyarr) << '\n';
}

void ArraySize1(int *arrMyarr)
{
    std::cout << sizeof(arrMyarr) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int arrTemp[] = { 122, 11, 22, 63, 15, 78, 143, 231 };
    std::cout << sizeof(arrTemp) << '\n';
    ArraySize(arrTemp);
    ArraySize1(arrTemp);
    return 0;
}
```

output:
32
4
4

Does below two declarations of functions are same?

`void ArraySize(int arrMyarr[]);`

`void ArraySize1(int *arrMyarr);`

Answer (score 6):

> Does below two declarations of functions are same?

Yes, completely. Arrays decay to a pointer to their first element when passed like that which is why you're seeing `4`. To prevent this, either use [`std:vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)`::size()` or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (C++11) for a compile time sized C-like array.

Answer (score 1):

> Does below two declarations of functions are same?

```
void ArraySize(int arrMyarr[]);

void ArraySize1(int *arrMyarr);
```

Yes, exactly the same. In the context of function parameter, `arrMyarr[]` in converted to `*arrMyarr` implicitly. This is so-called "array decays to pointer".

Answer (score 1):

> Yes the above two syntaxes for the functions are same

In both the cases we `passing reference to the first element` of an array in C++ i.e. `arrMyarr` .

Even if you were to put a number inside the brackets: in `void ArraySize(int arrMyarr[10])` the `10` is completely ignored

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you'd like to see the real size, you can do:

```
template<int N>
void ArraySize2(int (&arrMyarr)[N])
{
    std::cout << sizeof(arrMyarr) << '\n';
}
```

which shows 32.

(but also note that the template is instantiated for every different array size it is called with)

Can be also templatized for the type (to end up with the so-called "size of array" template).